# Plug-in architecture for ASP.NET MVC from ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack, pluggable

ServiceStack modules are so interesting. Iplugin interface also so good for Rest services. But where is pluggable mvc? :) Do you have any plan or else? 
When I say pluggable Mvc I mean Pluggable Areas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just simply ask if there are a plugin system for ASP.NET MVC3?

I've described how you can use my contrib project to create plugins: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/

Comment: Why I'm asking to ServiceStack? Because they are considering "Performance","Robustness"! I used 3rd party,free,open source Asp.Net MVC SiteMap Provider. But after a month making many manual corrections I recognize that there is so dramatic architectural performance problems on Provider. I don't want to make same mistake again. But I'll check your solution. Thanks. Best regards.

Comment: Yeah right, no other open source libraries consider performance or robustness.

Comment: I think, you've misunderstood me. Some open source libraries can have serious problem. Not all but some of them. According to me ServiceStack has high credibility. I respect your and all friends' effort. But you must think why there are so many different libraries for same problems? Also you have an answer why u made different approach than this:http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/

Comment: `why u made different approach` Because of the great support for Dependency Injection that MVC3 provided. `But you must think why there are so many different libraries for same problems?` Why? That's the beauty of open source. You get lots of different libraries to choose from.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I haven't argued against open source:) But sometimes choosing right one is so painfully.

Comment: I usually go by the available documentation. No documentation = I look at another project. Good documentation usually means disciplined programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ServiceStack's high-perf, testable caching, session, config and authentication/authorization components inside MVC websites as well - as described in [ServiceStack's MVC PowerPack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/).

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571450/should-servicestack-be-the-service-layer-in-an-mvc-application-or-should-it-call/10572977#10572977) shows how you can freely share any dependencies between ServiceStack and MVC by registering them in ServiceStack's built-in IOC and sharing them with MVC Controller factory.

Comment: I'm using it (PowerPack) :) Very good work! Yes you can use ServiceStack service in your controller (with performance penalty). But the question is more related with MVC Areas. Areas are not sharable between different Asp.Net MVC projects as dll.