# Using ServiceStack's AuthService with Controller and AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

There is no simple ServiceStack sample as classic ASP.NET MVC. Both AppHarbor and SocialBootStrap api based on SinglePage Application. How can I implement classic Asp.net MVC application with Servicestack's Authentication.

I've added  AuthService property to BaseController (Autowired). And then I got weird "object reference" exception while implemantation. ( AuthService line 135 base.RequestContext is null)

Why I'm getting this error? 
Or could anyone send simple usage. (Like Asp.net Mvc Membership Starter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services that make use of the RequestContext, needs to be the injected with the current Request Context, e.g:

```
authService.RequestContext = new HttpRequestContext(
    HttpContext.Current.Request.ToRequest(),
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ToResponse(),
    null
);
```

This uses extension methods in [SessionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/SessionExtensions.cs).

You will also want to resolve any Services from the IOC - here's a good example of [sharing functionality between ServiceStack and MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571450/should-servicestack-be-the-service-layer-in-an-mvc-application-or-should-it-call/10572977#10572977).

Comment: @ozz i am curious, how do you use the AuthService from BaseController to authorize access to action methods? I am trying the same with custom CredentialsAuthProvider but with no success.

Comment: I 've asked it also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236728/authentication-and-authorization-with-servicestack-mvc/11238758#11238758

Comment: Found the problem with my code: i was not setting session.IsAuthenticated = true, once the authentication was successful. I can confirm that [Authenticate] works pretty slick now.

Comment: This code does not work now.There is no ToRequest() or ToResponse extension.

Comment: @ozz Doesn't work is different to you are unable to find it. Use ReSharper or `Ctrl+Shift+F` Search for `ToRequest(this` or ask someone else to do the search for you. Either way, finding references is a solved problem which have many solutions.