# Authentication and Authorization with ServiceStack.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, servicestack

AuthorizeAttribute is useless while using ServiceStack.Mvc

AuthenticateAttribute is for DTO objects.

There is no sample for AccountController with ServiceStack, Signout is not working in SocialBootStrapApi.

Where is the basic Login,Logout,Authorize with Roles samples with ServiceStack.Mvc? (Not single page application, classic Asp.Net Mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't use the ASP.NET's or MVC's Authentication or anything that relies on it e.g. MVC's AccountController, it uses its own [Authentication Provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization).

AuthenticateAttribute and any other ServiceStack [Request or Response Filter attributes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) can in fact be used on both the DTO's and the Service.

If you inherit from [ServiceStackController](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs) then you can use ServiceStack's Attribute Filters in [[ExecuteServiceStackFilters]](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.cs) do get executed, e.g.

- [Authenticate]
- [RequiredRole]
- [RequiredPermission]

Comment: Two problem: When I use Authenticate attibute in base class it does not work.  Login Url is hardcoded how can I overwrrite it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301790/how-can-i-overwrite-login-url-in-servicestack-mvc-auhtentication

Comment: Does your base class inherit ServiceStackController?

Comment: XController inherits from YController (Y Controller has AuthenticateAttribute),  YController inherits from BaseController:ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>

Comment: In summary. XController:YController(has authenticate attribute):BaseController:ServiceStackController<CustomUserSession>  :)

Comment: On XController,BaseController ok. But on YController it does not work.

Comment: Sorry it is working only on XController . it does not work for YController and BaseController. For all scenerios "Executing Action" is on XController.

Comment: Both Public and Secure Controllers have been added to the SocialBootstrapApi project which both demonstrate the correct behaviour when using ServiceStack's [Authenticate] attribute. Add a pull-request for another Controller that demonstrates invalid behaviour.