# How can I overwrite Login Url in ServiceStack.MVC authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, servicestack

How can I override login Url?

Could you add it to AuthenticateAttribute as property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ServiceStacks' authentication mechanism you inherit from either `ServiceStackController` or `ServiceStackController<T>` which in turn inherits the former.

The login URL is dictated by the `LoginRedirectUrl` property of `ServiceStackController`.

```
public virtual string LoginRedirectUrl
{
    get { return "/login?redirect={0}"; }
}
```

Since it is virtual you can simply override it in your own Controller. Or even better, make your own abstract base controller that inherits from `ServiceStackController`. Then let all your controllers inherit that one. You now have a single point where you control things like the login URL.

```
public abstract class MyControllerBase : ServiceStackController
{
    public override string LoginRedirectUrl
    {
        get { return "/letslogin?redirectTo={0}"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's new, but looked at the code and it is actually just optional third parameter of AuthFeature constructor, so you can just:

```
//htmlRedirect is optional 3rd param of AuthFeature constructor, here passing "~/signin"
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] { new CredentialsAuthProvider(), }, "~/signin"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication namespace:

```
FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl
```

If you want to override the Web.config value, just implement your own authorize attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorize: AuthorizeAttribute{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
        //If the request does not provide authentication, then perform a redirect
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated) {
            var loginUrl = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl; //Change your URL here if needed.

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(loginUrl);
        } else {
            //Since the request was authenticated, perform the default authorization check.
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is for different Authentication mechanizm. ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.AuthenticateAttribute