# ServiceStack How to call my service from code

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

how can i call my own service?

I have a service that use other services to compose information.

I want to call other services within the code of this service.

How can I do that?

Comment: Borrowed this question from chat room, I think it is useful to document it for others.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a base method called `base.ResolveService<TMyService>()` which just resolves your autowired service from the IOC and injects the current request context

So just call:

```
using (var service = base.ResolveService<MyService>()) { 
    service.Post(new MyRequest()); 
}
```

You can also call a Service with just a Request DTO which will also execute the Services Global Request Filters:

```
base.ExecuteRequest(new MyRequest());
```

This is just a wrapper around ServiceController which can be called statically:

```
HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(new MyRequest(), base.Request)
```

Comment: How do I call this from my ASP.NET MVC Controller? Since my Controller does not inherit from `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface`.

Comment: @RosdiKasim, here is a link to mythz's answer about a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571450/should-servicestack-be-the-service-layer-in-an-mvc-application-or-should-it-call

Comment: Hi thanks Tom!.. that link is really helpful.. appreciate the help.

Comment: HI @mythz is there a way to do this that also runs the fluent validation for the request? thanks

Comment: Does this still apply with "new style" services... I can't see `base.ExecuteRequest` on them?

Comment: Using base.ExecuteRequest(new MyRequest());, can we define if we want the override OnGet/OnPost to be executed ? And at the same time, how do we get the returned response from the internally called methods ? 

Or is there a way i can find the corresponding IReturn Type, so i can use 
using (var service = base.ResolveService<MyType>()) - then i could use the service.Post and service.Get methods as required.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Jumping in a bit late, since this popped up on a search engine.  The new way as of about ServiceStack v4.5 is to use [ServiceGateway](http://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway).  Every SS `Service` now has a `Gateway` property which can be executed against:

```
var response = this.Gateway.Send(new MyRequest());
```