# Error calling ServiceStack service with mvc4 Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, servicestack

I'm trying to figure out how to call a service from an asp mvc4 controller, but I just can't. I already set up the services but when I'm trying to call from my controller method it displays this :

http://s10.postimg.org/5ojcryn7t/error_1.png

Here's my code:

Global.asax.cs

```
namespace mvc4_servicestack
{
// Nota: para obtener instrucciones sobre cómo habilitar el modo clásico de IIS6 o IIS7, 
// visite http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        public class AppHost : AppHostBase
        {
            public AppHost()
                : base("Nombre del Host de los WebService", typeof(SS_WebServices.StatusService).Assembly)
            { }

            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
            {

            }



        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {

            new AppHost().Init();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

           // WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();


        }
    }
}
```

## SS_WebServices.cs

namespace mvc4_servicestack
{
    public class SS_WebServices
    {

```
    //Request DTO Objet
    [ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Route("/Home/About/statuss")]
    [ServiceStack.ServiceHost.Route("/Home/About/statuss/{Name}")]
    public class StatusQuery : ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IReturn<StatusResponse>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }

    //Response DTO Object
    public class StatusResponse
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
    }


    //Service
    public class StatusService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service
    {
        //Implement teh Method VERB (POST,GET,PUT,DELETE) OR Any for ALL VERBS
        public object Any(StatusQuery request)
        {
            //Looks strange when the name is null so we replace with a generic name.
            var name = request.Name ?? "John Doe";
            return new StatusResponse { Result = "Hello, " + name };
        }
    }


}
```

}

I've been reading the post [Should ServiceStack be the service layer in an MVC application or should it call the service layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571450/should-servicestack-be-the-service-layer-in-an-mvc-application-or-should-it-call)

But Still I can't understand things like :
WHY Register returns an Interface instead a GreeterResponse? container.Register(c => new Greeter());

I really hope you guys can help me...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ServiceStack is hosted in the same AppDomain as MVC, you don't need to use a ServiceClient and go through HTTP to access ServiceStack Services, instead you can just [resolve and call the Service normally](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration#calling-servicestack-services-from-mvc-controllers), E.g:

```
public HelloController : ServiceStackController 
{
    public void Index(string name) 
    {
        using (var svc = base.ResolveService<HelloService>())
        {
           ViewBag.GreetResult = svc.Get(name).Result;
           return View();
        }
    }        
}
```

> Outside of a Controller a ServiceStack Service can be resolved via `HostContext.ResolveService<T>()`

See the [MVC Integration docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) for more info.

> But Still I can't understand things like : WHY Register returns an Interface instead a GreeterResponse? container.Register(c => new Greeter());

Greeter is just a normal C# dependency (i.e. it's not a ServiceStack Service). The container isn't returning `IGreeter` here, instead it's saying to "Register the Greeter implemenation against the IGreeter interface":

```
container.Register<IGreeter>(c => new Greeter());
```

If you registered it without, it will just be registered against the concrete type, e.g. these are both equivalent:

```
container.Register(c => new Greeter());
container.Register<Greeter>(c => new Greeter());
```

Which means you would need to specify the concrete dependency to get it auto-wired, e.g:

```
public class MyService : Service 
{
    public Greeter Greeter { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of being able to use:

```
    public IGreeter Greeter { get; set; }
```

Which is much easier to test given that it's a mockable interface.

Comment: I'm not sure if you watch all the code I post....or I'm confused because in my StatusService I do not have a method GET instead I have a method Any(StatusQuery request) wich return a StatusResponse object. So I really can't understand the code you paste.

Comment: These are the errors I get when I try that code
[link]http://s24.postimg.org/500b3m7it/error2.png
[link]http://s7.postimg.org/a8lx5y48r/error3.png 

@mythz

Comment: @user1629278 You're calling your own class just like a normal C# method call - you only have `Any()` defined in your service so call that instead (if that's what you want to do).

Comment: I just did it but still get the error at the ResolveService? Why?
[link]http://s13.postimg.org/e1g9wlvsn/error4.png @mythz

Comment: @user1629278 You just need to provide `HttpContext.Current`. See updated answer.

Comment: In MVC4, `HttpContext.Current` does not resolve. You need `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`