# Is RequestFilter Validation client dependent?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, applicationhost, servicestack-bsd

Should I expect Request Filter Validation (e.g. [FluentValidation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation#fluentvalidation-for-request-dtos)) to be triggered when [instantiating a reference service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571450/should-servicestack-be-the-service-layer-in-an-mvc-application-or-should-it-call/10572977#10572977) via `AppHostBase.ResolveService<>`?

Thus far, I've only successfully received proper error responses to my C# application when using the [typed clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Clients-overview) ([JsonServiceClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) in this case specifically).

Comment: I'll be verifying this afternoon.

Comment: `protected IServiceController ServiceController` on `AppHostBase`...can't figure out how to access this from an MVC controller.

Comment: I have the entire [v3 branch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v3) on my machine and cannot locate a `HostContext.ServiceController`, extension or otherwise. `ServiceStack.Common.HostContext`

Comment: Jeremy I have updated my answer to include the v3 method, sorry I hadn't realised you were using v3, and had provided instructions for v4. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If you try use `AppHostBase.ResolveService<T>` it does not execute any of the registered request filters. Essentially it only resolves the Service from the AppHost dependancy container, you get back just the Service instance. Thus your validators aren't triggered.

### ServiceStack v4:

As @mythz points out you can use the MQ entry point API of the `HostContext` to execute the call with the MQ request filters and thus have the validation run. To do this:

```
HostContext.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(new Message<T>(requestDto), httpReq);
```

@mythz also notes you can execute a service using just a DTO, rather than having to determine the service and handling method to call, but in a similar fashion to `AppHostBase.ResolveService<T>` it *doesn't* trigger the request filters. Usage:

```
HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(requestDto, httpReq)
```

### ServiceStack v3:

```
GetAppHost().Config.ServiceManager.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(new Message<T>(requestDto), httpReq);
```

Comment: You can also call a service with just a request DTO with: `HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(requestDto, httpReq)`, this still doesn't execute the Global Request Filters but using the MQ entry point API: `HostContext.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage(new Message<T>(requestDto), httpReq)` does execute the global MQ request filters and execute the Fluent Validation.

Comment: @mythz That's great. I'm going off to explore the `HostContext` source code properly; That's twice now you pointed out great features I didn't know possible. :)

Comment: what do you pass as `httpReq`?

Comment: @JeremySmith If you don't pass `httpReq` I believe it will resolve the context from the original request. The relevant code [is here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/ServiceController.cs#L466). So simply try passing the DTO.

Comment: I've confirmed it does trigger validation as desired. Oddly, it's only working for `POST` or `ANY`...throwing `Could not find method named Post(...) or Any(...) on Service ...` for any other method...while this works, it's a bit clunky. I'll likely avoid the request filter validation completely and just perform validation within service methods. Thanks for revealing this nugget!