# Calling one ServiceStack 4 service from another with a file upload thrown in for fun

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a working service in 4.0.31 that looks like this:

```
public object Post(MyDTO request)
{
   foreach (var uploadedFile in base.Request.Files)
   {
      ... do something ...
   }
   return new MyDTOResponse();
}
```

Everything works great, and I'm happy!

But now, I want to call the same service method from within another service, the way to do this apparently is:

```
public object Post(MyOtherDTO request)
{
  var myService = base.ResolveService<MyService>();
  // now I call some new method I wrote to bypass the file upload part, since
  // myService.Post() doesn't know about the file upload part
  var myResponse = myService.NewMethodThatLetsMePassAStreamToTheOtherService(streamData);
  ... do other stuff...
  return new MyOtherDTOResponse();
}
```

While I'm not *unhappy* with this, it does create a hard dependency between the two services, so I'm not *thrilled* like I usually am with ServiceStack!

Is there a more elegant way of putting this together?  I'm probably just missing something really, really obvious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what the issue is, if it's how to share logic between services? then you could pull common logic out of each service class and reference the shared code in both Services.

If no dependencies are required I'll refactor the shared code behind re-usable **extension methods**.

If dependencies are required I will refactor it behind a shared logic class that's a dependency in both Services, see the `IGreeter` example in the [sharing logic between MVC and ServiceStack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572977/85785):

```
public class MyService1 : Service
{
    public ISharedDep SharedDep { get; set] 

    public object Any(Request1 request)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class MyService2 : Service
{
    public ISharedDep SharedDep { get; set] 

    public object Any(Request2 request)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

#### Shared logic using Request Context using base class

If it's common code used by many Services that requires the `base.Request` context than you could move it to a common Service base class:

```
public class MyServiceBase : Service
{
    public ISharedDep SharedDep { get; set] 

    public object SharedMethod(object request)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class MyServices1 : MyServiceBase { ... }
public class MyServices2 : MyServiceBase { ... }
```

#### Shared logic using Request Context using Extension method

If you prefer not to use a base class, this can be re-factored behind an extension method as well:

```
public static void MyServiceExtensions
{
    public static object SharedMethod(this IServicBase service, object request)
    {
        var sharedDep = service.TryResolve<ISharedDep>();
        return sharedDep.SharedMethodWithRequestCtx(request, service.Request);
    }
}
```

#### Loose Coupling by executing a Request DTO

If the issue is about a loose-coupled way to call Services without a reference to the implementation itself you can execute the Request DTO with the ServiceController:

```
public class MyService : Service
{
    public object Any(Request requestDto)
    {
        var altDto = new AltRequest { Id = requestDto.Id };
        var response = HostContext.ServiceController.Execute(altDto, base.Request);
        //...
    }
}
```

> Note: this API is available as `base.ExecuteRequest(requestDto)` in v4.0.32+.

### Uploading Files to a HTTP Service In Memory

If the issue is instead how to execute a Service that handles file uploads, there's an [example in the embedded version of HttpBenchmarks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Gap#uploading-files-to-a-http-service-in-memory) showing how to call a Service that processes HTTP File uploads with a custom Request Context that uses local FileSystem files instead:

```
using (var admin = Resolve<AdminServices>())
{
    //...
    var dir = new FileSystemVirtualPathProvider(this, Config.WebHostPhysicalPath);
    var files = dir.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.txt")
        .Concat(dir.GetAllMatchingFiles("*.zip"));

    admin.Request = new BasicRequest
    {
        Files = files.Map(x => new HttpFile {
            ContentLength = x.Length,
            ContentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(x.Name),
            FileName = x.Name,
            InputStream = x.OpenRead(),
        } as IHttpFile).ToArray()
    };

    if (admin.Request.Files.Length > 0)
    {
        admin.Post(new UploadTestResults
        {
            TestPlanId = 1,
            TestRunId = testRun.Id,
            CreateNewTestRuns = true,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As always, I was making things more complicated than necessary.  Thanks for the tips.

Comment: You probably have guessed this already, but your 'Loose Coupling by executing a Request DTO' example brings me back to my normal _Thrilled_with_Servicestack_ status!